# NPM install mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Recently i messed up my mongodb server but i fixed it and everything is going smoothly except this one directory. When i npm install mongoose back into this dir, it works and everything, but the node_modolus folder that's suppose to pop up doesnt

```
door_bells:~/workspace/Associations.1 $ npm install mongoose
mongoose@4.5.10 ../../node_modules/mongoose
├── sliced@1.0.1
├── ms@0.7.1
├── hooks-fixed@1.2.0
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── async@1.5.2
├── muri@1.1.0
├── mpromise@0.5.5
├── kareem@1.1.3
├── mpath@0.2.1
├── bson@0.4.23
├── mquery@1.11.0 (debug@2.2.0, sliced@0.0.5, bluebird@2.10.2)
└── mongodb@2.1.18 (es6-promise@3.0.2, readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.3.18)
```

also when i try runnning a js file in this dir, this is the error i get:

```
door_bells:~/workspace/Associations $ node embed.js
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of null
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/Associations/embed.js:56:12
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3327:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:259:21
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

---

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String,
    posts: [postSchema] 
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

User.findOne({name: 'sl'}, function(err,user){ 
   if(err) {
       console.log(err); 
   } else { 
       user.posts.push({ 
           title: '3 Things i really hate',
           content: 'uuK,SyY,x'
       });
       user.save(function(err,user){ //user save
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
               console.log(user);
           }
       });
   } 
});
```

Comment: What is the code in embed.js?

Comment: hey, sorry for the late reply, this is the code

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear from your question if you have one or two issues. For the 'posts' issue it may be because your are not finding a matching user. You should check for that:

```
User.findOne({name: 'sl'}, function(err,user){ 
 if(err) {
   console.log(err); 
 } else { 
   // There is no reason to assume 'user' exists here. Checking for errors would not show this.
   user.posts.push({
```

So...

```
if(user) {
   user.posts.push({
```

As far as your question about `node_modules`. Not totally clear if you actually have an issue. There are cases when things do get messed up and in those cases I delete the entire `node_modules` folder and recreate it.

```
rm -rf node_modules // be sure to be in you project directory - or delete by hand if you prefer
npm i  // Reinstall it all
```